# "Release" the variable on the left side of equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have a particular formula ([source](http://www.patarnott.com/atms360/pdf_atms360/solareqns.pdf)) for solar azimuth angle, which I would like to derive in a way, that on the left side I have teta only(that's the solar azimuth angle) and on the left side everything else.
The initial formula goes like this:

```
cos(180 - teta) = - (sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi))
```

What I tried is to "release" the teta on the left, like so:

```
cos(180)*cos(teta) + sin(180)*sin(teta) = - (sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi))

-1*cos(teta) + 0*sin(teta) = - (sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi))

- cos(teta) = - (sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi))

cos(teta) = (sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi))

teta = arccos((sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi)))
```

Is this correct?

The problem is that when using this last formula with certain variables, the result does not look correct.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have solved the first equation for $\theta$ correctly, you could have used the shortcut $\cos(180^\circ-\theta)=-\cos\theta$ though.

- According to the source your $\theta$ is measured clockwise from north, where it is  $\theta=0$, but in the trigonometric circle the angles are measure from $(1,0)$ anticlockwise.
- The range of the inverse trigonometric function $\theta=\arccos x$ is $0^\circ\le \theta\le 180^\circ$, but in the full trigonometric circle ($[0^\circ,360^\circ]$) there are two angles $\theta$ with the same $\cos \theta=x$. Let $\theta_1,\theta_2$ be those angles and $\cos \theta_1=\cos \theta_2=x$. If $0^\circ\le \theta_1\le 180^\circ$, then $\theta_2$ is such that $\theta_1+\theta_2=360^\circ$, which mean that both $\theta_1,\theta_2$ lie on the right or the left half-plane containing the trigonometric circle. So $180^\circ\le \theta_2\le 360^\circ$. Hence only knowing if $\theta$ is on the upper half-plane or on lower-upper plane, you can decide for $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$.

Example: If $\theta_1=60^\circ$, then $\theta_2=360^\circ-60^\circ=300^\circ$, and $\cos 60^\circ=\cos 300^\circ=1/2$, while $\theta=\arccos 1/2=60^\circ$ only. If the solution of your equation is $\theta=300^\circ$, the formula `teta = arccos((sin(lat)*cos(phi) - sin(decl)) / (cos(lat)*sin(phi)))` will not give it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Américo.
I did not understand you though. Can you give me an example with teta1 and teta2 angles? Obrigado

Comment: @Bernard De nada! See my edit with an example.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the solution to this problem, as arccos can not be used to determine teta angle?

Comment: It seems to me that one has to know the exact conventions the formula uses for the different angles. Furthermore the clarification requires some technical knowledge and it would help very much to see how the first formula in your post was derived. The [Solar azimuth angle wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_azimuth_angle#Formulas) presents similar but not quite the same formulas. To avoid such ambiguities sometimes one uses the [atan2 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) instead. Sorry, but I cannot help you further.

Comment: Thank you for the help Américo.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this: suppose I tell you that $\cos \theta = 0.7071$. You may say "OK, so $\theta$ is 45 degrees." But it's also possible that $\theta = 315$ degrees. Just knowing the cosine doesn't tell you the angle.

Arccos is a great function...but it doesn't fix the problem I've described. "$\arccos(s)$" will give you the angle, $r$, between 0 and 180, whose cosine is the number $s$. But there's always another such number as well, namely $-r$ (or $360-r$, if you prefer). So you cannot, from the information you've got so far, hope to actually recover the angle "teta".

Comment: Thank you for the help John.